# Move unequal numbers of characters per cell to another column single cell with limited range

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to move characters of first column cells to another column but the second column should have no more than 25 characters per cell. For example, in first column each out of first 5 rows cells has 5 characters which will migrate to the second column single cell with total 25 characters, rows 6,7,8 may have 7 characters, row 9 may have 8 characters. So, just rows 6,7,8 (total 21 character) will migrate to the second column. Row 9 will go with the next one which together may result 25 or a bit less number of characters.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User Irina! What have you tried so far? What part specifically is causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A:A),(ROWS($1:1)-1)*25+1,25)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

The formula concatenates all the data in column **A**.  It then take 25 character "chunks" and places them in column **B**.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a macro based solution.  The macro walks down column **A** building a string through concatenation.  Before the string grows past 25 characters, it is stored in a column **B** cell and a new string gets started.  The macro:

```
Sub Kompactor()
    Dim txt As String, K As Long, i As Long
    txt = ""
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To 25
    If Len(txt & Cells(i, 1)) > 25 Then
        Cells(K, 2) = txt
        txt = Cells(i, 1)
        K = K + 1
    Else
        txt = txt & Cells(i, 1)
    End If
    Next i

    Cells(K, 2) = txt
End Sub
```

some sample data:

[image]

As you see A1,A2,A3,A4 go into B1
A5,A6,A7 go into B2
etc.

Comment: Thank you but I need to fill the cell in B column 25 or less characters because each cell in column A may have different number of characters and eventually all of them will become labels. So, I cannot have part of label split between 2 different cells in column B

Comment: @ИринаЖебрак I understand now...............I will need to think about this...........................